# Where do Oracle Functions like TZ_Offset and FROM_TZ get their data from?

Tags: oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm working on optimizing some functions in which I need to convert many timestamps to UTC. My need is to create a table with the columns as follows:

YEAR | TZ_NAME | Start of Daylight Savings | End of Daylight Savings

I can convert the timestamps easily using the from_tz function in oracle, however running this per timestamp isn't an option. Does anyone know how the oracle function works? I can't find any documentation that details where oracle keeps these daylight savings rules.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this side: http://www.iana.org/time-zones Oracle uses the same source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone related information is stored in a file, as per: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006667

> The Oracle time zone files contain the valid time zone names. The
>   following information is also included for each time zone:
>
> •Offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
>
> •Transition times for Daylight Saving Time
>
> •Abbreviations for standard time and Daylight Saving Time

Comment: I suppose this is as good as it will get for me.. I was hoping there was a secret view that Oracle might provide on top of this file to give more visibility. Thanks for providing that link.

Comment: Sadly, not that I could find (I queried dba_views to see if there was anything with TIME%ZONE in the name, but only v$timezone_file and v$timezone_names were there), neither of which has the info you're after.

Comment: Just a note, daylight saving times and time zones are not as constant as most people think about. For example, have a look at [Singapore Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time) or [Time in Malaysia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Malaysia), within 80 years they changed their time zone 6 times!

Comment: It's definitely a difficult rule set to maintain, which is why everyone should just store times in UTC! I found this collection of best practices to be interesting: [DST and TZ Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices?rq=1)